# What is the following codes meaning in rspec source code?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Recently I was reading the source code of rspec and had lots of questions.

1, What is the following code meaning in rspec source code?

```
OptionParser < ::OptionParser
```

2, I found that when the runner was running, there is a Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_n object created, but i can not find the where this Class defined, need help to understand this.

My rspec version is 1.3.0

Comment: It's a good idea to link to the file in which it's contained.

Comment: If you are asking two questions, you should ask two questions, not stuff both of them into one question. That way, you can give both of them a meaningful title, and thus give others who have the same question a chance to find it via Google. "*What is the following codes meaning in rspec source code?*" isn't exactly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the following code meaning in
>   rspec source code?
>
> `OptionParser < ::OptionParser`

The [context](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/v1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/option_parser.rb#L6) is helpful to understand this. This is creating a new class, `Spec::Runner::OptionParser` that is a subclass of the [top-level class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html) `OptionParser`.  The `::` is there to force it to use the top-level class so that it does not attempt to subclass itself.

> I found that when the runner was
>   running, there is a
>   Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_n
>   object created, but i can not find the
>   where this Class defined, need help to
>   understand this.

Each example group that you create is a dynamically defined subclass of `Spec::Example::ExampleGroup`.  You can see where it dynamically sets the name [here](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/v1.3.2/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb#L185).